# Booting to black screen after system freeze

Tags: boot, black-screen

So a few days ago I had my system freeze completely. Waited a good 20 minutes to see if it would unfreeze, but it did not. I was forced to shut down my machine by holding down the power button on my tower. This caused some form of booting issue though.

If I let my machine boot regularly, I'm just hit with a black screen where I'm supposed to enter my password to enter my DE. Things seems to be running normally besides the black screen, as I do have access to my media via Plex and such. Can't really do much with a black screen though.

I tried accessing GRUB and boot with an older kernel (5.11.0-27-generic, according to uname -a) instead of the latest current one (If I'm not mistaken, that one is -32 or -34). With the old kernel it boots just fine, but if I try the latest one, the black screen is there. Can't really use the old kernel indefinitely as I can't update packages, like my GPU drivers and the like as I'm hit with an error message if I try.

I've tried some google, but all I was able to find were black screens in relations to fresh installs of Ubuntu, which doesn't really apply to my situation. I also found a suggestion to reinstall GRUB, which I did and it did not resolve this issue.

I'm running Elementary OS 6. Any help to get this resolved would be greatly appreciated. Would prefer not having to reinstall my OS, at least for a few more weeks as I'm currently studying and don't really want to set up my lab environment all over again as that's quite the time sink.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to the eOS community. Do you remember what your machine was doing when the freeze occurred? How did the freeze manifest itself?

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at YouTube, having a few more tabs than necessary open. Other than that I didn't really have anything running, besides htop in my terminal. In the middle of the video everything just froze, couldn't move my mouse cursor or anything, a complete system freeze.

Comment: What if you install this kernel? `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04` Also, please add your system specs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try installing it, but when I tried booting with it, it froze at "loading initial ramdisk". My specs are: AMD FX-6300, 12GB RAM, GTX 680, SanDisk SSD.